# How do customize a popup like Snackbar or Notification dialog with a message?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am trying to include a feature in my app that examines the values of a column in a user-uploaded Google sheet and verifies whether they are correct or not. If there are any incorrect values, a popup like Snackbar or Notification dialog will appear listing the incorrect values. If there are no incorrect values, no popup will appear. How do you display a popup with different values depending on the situation? Is there a way to display unique popups directly from the ServerScript without having to create separate pages? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do what you want.  You need to use Templated HTML.  From the code editor, choose "Help" and then choose "Documentation."  Then in the side menu choose Guides and then Templated HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either by direct interaction with Snackbar's children widgets or by binding them to [Custom Properties](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties):

```javascript
// option 1
app.popups.Snackbar.descendants.SnackbarText.text = message;

// option 2
app.popups.Snackbar.properties.Text = message;

app.popups.Snackbar.visible = true;
```

You can see first option implementation sample here - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/jdbc/

Answer (score 0):

You can create one Snackbar page. In that Page you should have Textbox at the bottom. You can bind that Textbox's value to custom function like `getNotificationText();` 
[image: Bind getNotificationText() function]

In the client script right the following code in the common script.

```
//Client script
var notificationText='';
function setNotificationText(text)
{
  notificationText=text;
}
function getNotificationText()
{
  return notificationText;
}
```

Once you do this, you can write following lines from your different methods to display message.

```
//Client script
setNotificationText('Your message.');
app.popups.Snackbar.visible = true;
```